# Java replaceAll() non-numeric and negative numbers?

Tags: java, regex

Beginner here. How do I use regex to replace a string with only its non-numeric (including negative) substring?

Example:

```
String src = "Copper=-32"

Regex output should be "-32"
```

I've been trying to use:

```
src = src.replaceAll("\\D+",""); <----- used various regex patterns, which don't work.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you only expecting integers, or can there also be decimals, scientific notation etc.?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Only integers

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend.  When I search on "regex for number" you get an answer with a good explanation: [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).  Their final answer is

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+.
```

but it is well worth reading the article to see pitfalls.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the replacement needs to be done several time it would be worth refactoring to java `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to replace integer values, try

```
String src = "Copper=-32";
System.out.println(src.replaceAll("\\d+",""));
```

The important thing to denote is the lower case d.

If you want to remove the negative/positive signs then use:

```
String src = "Copper=-32";
System.out.println(src.replaceAll("[-+]?\\d+",""));
```

The `[]` allows you to specify a list of characters you wish to match in that position. So we're basically saying match a + or - followed by many digits.

**Edit** Added ? after the `[-+]` to make it optional. Thanks to user949300 for pointing it out.

Comment: You should put a ? after the `[-+]` to make the sign optional.